# Java: illegal start of expression error

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
```

public class ReadCSV {

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
ReadCSV obj = new ReadCSV();
obj.run();
//obj.setUpMyCSV();
//obj.printMyArray();
```

}

public void run() {

```
String csvFile = "C:/Users/Aditi Site/Desktop/infert.csv";
File file = new File(csvFile);
BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";
String csvSplitBy = ",";

try {
    int sum=0;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
        String[] infert = line.split(csvSplitBy);

        System.out.println("infert [education= " + infert[1] 
                            + " , age=" + infert[2] + " , parity=" + infert[3] +" , induced=" + infert[4] +" , case=" + infert[5] +" , spontaneous=" + infert[6] +" , stratum=" + infert[7] +" , pooled.stratum=" + infert[8] +"]");

        }



} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (br != null) {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

//I am getting error in following method:

```
public void setUpMyCSV()
{
Double myArray=new double[200][200];
Scanner scanIn=null;
int r=0;
int rc=0;
int cc=0;
int c=0;
String Inputline=" ";
double xnum=0;
String xfilelocation;
xfilelocation= "C:/Users/Aditi Site/Desktop/infert.csv";
try
    {
    scanIn=new Scanner(new BufferedReader(newFileReader (xfilelocation)));
    while(scanIn.hasNextLine())
    {   InputLine=scanIn.nextLine();
        String[] InArray=InputLine.split(",");
        for(int x=0;x<InArray.length;x++)
        {
        myArray[rc][x]=Double.parseDouble(InArray[x]);
        }
        rc++;

    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

//I am getting error in following method:

```
public void printMyArray()
{
Double myArray=new double[200][200];
for(int rc=0;r<130;r++)
    {
        for(int cc=0;c<130;c++)
        {
            System.out.println(myArray[rc][cc]+ "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
//return;
}
```

}
}

I am getting following error:
illegal start of expression
public void printMyArrat
public void setUpMyCSV

Comment: Count your closing curly braces. It looks like you have too many of them.

Comment: missing proper formatting, and stacktrace. plz add

Comment: Ideally, produce a *short* but complete program demonstrating the problem. I suspect that between formatting your code properly and reducing the problem to a minimal example, you'll discover the issue for yourself.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a closing bracket at your first method.

Comment: `run() {` is not closed by a curley bracket.

Comment: I actually pasted your code in eclipse and I had to correct ~10 typos.

Answer (score 0):

You havent closed your run method. Close it by adding "}" (close brace) just before `public void setUpMyCSV()`